# Where could I find a sample simple chain spec for substrate?

Tags: substrate-node-template

Where could I find a sample simple chain spec for substrate ready for production?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just export one from substrate-node-template ? You can run the following cmd:

```
${path-to-substrate-template-binary} build-spec
```

Answer (score 2):

Some parachain teams commit them to their Github (so poke around in their Substrate repos).

You can see Polkadot's chain spec here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/node/service/chain-specs/polkadot.json

There are several others from the ecosystem:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/node/service/chain-specs

Answer (score 1):

**Relay chain**

The [Local relay chain tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-relay/#relay-chain-specification) on substrate.io has links to predefined [rococo chain specs](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/tree/main/static/assets/tutorials/cumulus/chain-specs) for local use. You can download the plain version and browse it.

**Parachain**

The [Connect a local parachain tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-parachain/#custom-parachain-specification) has instructions how to generate (and modify) specs from the parachain template

```
./target/release/parachain-collator build-spec --disable-default-bootnode > rococo-local-parachain-plain.json
```

You can generate one and browse it.